# Regex matching beginning, ending and contains strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex that matches an expression that :

- start with a string (in my example : `<div`)
- ends with another string (in my example : `</div>`)
- contains a searched string (in my example : `searched string`).

Around this searched string can be anything included spaces and newlines.

Parsing : `<div class="testclass">random example text</div>
<div id="testid">foo bar foo searched string foo bar</div>`

Should match :
`<div id="testid">foo bar foo searched string foo bar</div>`

The first `<div>` should not match, as it doesn't contain `searched string`

I've tried something like :
`^(<div)(.|\s)*?(searched string)(.|\s)*?(</div>)$`

But obviously it returns the whole tested expression as the `(.|\s)*?` part matches everything until it finds the searched string.

I want the RegEx to reject the `<div class="testclass">random example text</div>` part, as it does not contain `searched string`

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I'm using sublime text 3 to perform this search, and for what I understand, it uses a custom proprietary regex engine, but I guess the logic could be similar to other languages like php.

Comment: What app/language you working with? Is there no way to use a proper parser?

Comment: Don't know in which dialect you use regex. In R, this could be a solution: `v <- '<div class="testclass">random example text</div>
  <div id="testid">foo bar foo searched string foo bar</div>'
gsub('.*(<div.*searched string.*</div>).*', '\\1', v )`.

Comment: I'm using sublime text 3 to perform this search (edited the question)

Comment: @LucasDemea Is there any new lines in the `<div>`?

Comment: Yes, it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget:

> [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
>   HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

---

But, if you really want a regex, use:

```
<div[^>]*>(?:(?!</div>)[\s\S])*searched string(?:(?!</div)[\s\S])*</div>
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/88U8ef/1)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. Actually I don't think I can use a parser because the code i'm parsing is html mixed with other special tags (wordpress shortcodes) that I have to clean out. The code I wrote here is only a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, for the sake of readability. Not sure a parser could work in this situation, but if so I would be happy to learn which tool to use